# update one table insterting a column correspondance to similar field of other table

Tags: mysql

```
update `tblapplicationcom` 
set ApplicationDate= (
    select ApplicationDate 
    from tblimportapplication) 
where tblapplicationcom.ApplicationID in (
    select Applicationid 
    from tblimportapplication 
    where tblimportapplication.Applicationid = tblapplicationcom.ApplicationID)
```

i have been trying this code but couldn't get well. 
what i want is
table #1
Applicationid (pk)
ApplciationDate

Table #2
RecordID (pk)
ApplicationID (FK)
ApplicationDate

i want to update ApplicationDate of table #2 as of ApplicationDate of table #1 where table2.applicationid = table1.applicationid

Comment: Could you restate of what you want to do pls? Maybe sample row of what you have and what u want it to be after update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax when you need to update with values from another table:

```
update tblapplicationcom a
join tblimportapplication b on a.Applicationid = b.ApplicationID
set a.ApplicationDate = b.ApplicationDate;
```